# change default invoice report to custom report?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

in my custom module I am trying to change default invoice report to custom report. this is report tag

```
     <report 
        id="account.account_invoices"
        model="account.invoice"
        string="Invoice custom report"
        report_type="qweb-pdf"
        name="custom_invoice_report.custom_invoice_template"
        file="custom_invoice_report.custom_invoice_template"
    />
```

I also defined the `<template id="custom_invoice_template">` in my code.
but the default invoice report is printed.How to change this custom report?

***note***

I use `id="account.account_invoices` for loading send mail attachment.The send mail attachment is loaded based this id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to add attribute *attachment_use="False"* to load new report changes. In invoice report has *attachment_use="True"* means once we print report and output will be same at the end.

Try with following code:

```
<report 
    id="account.account_invoices"
    model="account.invoice"
    string="Invoice custom report"
    report_type="qweb-pdf"
    attachment_use="False"
    name="custom_invoice_report.custom_invoice_template"
    file="custom_invoice_report.custom_invoice_template"
/>
```